# Jquery AJAX type property

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, types, request

I was looking into couchdb for the first time and wannted to make an interface using jquery. When trying to send an AJAX call to the API service(it does different things depending on the method of the http request), so when I set a "type" property, it always does a GET request, no matter if its set to POST, PUT, DELETE or GET.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5984/newDBNAME",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'PUT',

    success:function(data){
        alert(data.db_name);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set the dataType to jsonp, jsonp only supports GET.

Answer (score 1):

jsonp requests will *always* be get. What is technically happening here is jQuery is creating a script tag with the src set to the url (with the success function linked to the callback function appended to the end of the url, which jQuery handles automatically behind the scenes).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but is there a way to make json retuns work, and not get the Origin null error and w/e it was in firefox